# Is this the correct way to share a instance of a Redis client in Express?

Tags: javascript, express, redis

Due to I have the application routes dedined in separated scripts I need a way to share the same Redis client across all of them. Is this the correct way of doing it ?

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.redis = client;
    next();
});

// load routes

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

... other js file

```
app.get('/xyz', (req, res) => {
    var redis = red.redis;
    // use redis
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're un-necessarily passing your client instance to every request regardless of if it's needed.

I use a pretty standard controller which you can then require() as needed, example below.

```
var redis = require('redis')
    .createClient(...);
redis.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Redis server online.');
});
module.exports = redis;
```

Then whenever you want to access it

```
var redis = require('./app/controllers/redis');
// redis => Redis client instance
```